# Erlang SASL AUTH PROTOCOL implementation

Tags: security, authentication, erlang, couchdb, sasl

Many Systems are beginning to use this [SASLAuthProtocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Authentication_and_Security_Layer) (see [RFC4422](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4422)) for authenticating Clients in RESTFUL interactions. Examples are: Couchbase Server 2.0, Memcached e.t.c. I wonder if there is an erlang complete implementation of this authentication protocol. A [Java implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/sasl/sasl-refguide.html) is a good example of what i am looking for. This [Python Code](https://github.com/membase/ep-engine/blob/master/management/mc_bin_client.py) seems to be the python implementation of this protocol. Is there an Erlang library i can quickly use to have SASLAuth support in my Application ?

Answer (score 3):

I've not tried this, but it looks like it implements SASL for Erlang:

https://github.com/mikma/esasl

When searching for this kind of thing, take care to avoid the SASL in Erlang, which is System Architecture Support Libraries - "these are not the SASL you're looking for"...

Comment: true. Erlang has its own `SASL`, but its NOT the AUTH PROTOCOL in this Context. Thanks @Seb

Comment: This Library has no `README` and so, using it is becoming a problem